# Parameter study using python

Tags: python, csv, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a file called pattern.pc with content like this:

```
<p1> bla bla 
<p2> bla bla
```

now I would like to replace the `<p1>` and `<p2>` with some values which are in separate file (let say parameter_values.pc) e.g the values for the p1 are in the first line and those for the p2 in the second line:

```
1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0
10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0
```

and get new files like this (here for `p1 = 1.0` and for `p2 = 10.0`):

```
1.0 bla bla
10.0 bla bla
```

which will be named e.g pattern_p1_1_p2_10.pc and so on. Could you help to do it in python. I forgot to mention that all possible combinations between the parameters values are acceptable - in this particular case we will have at the end 16 new files. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# assumes Python 2.7

PARAMETERS_FILE = "parameter_values.pc"
PATTERN_FILE    = "pattern.pc"
OUTPUT_NAME     = "pattern_p1_{p1}_p2_{p2}.pc"

def strs(line, split_on=None):
    return [s.strip() for s in line.split(split_on)]

def main():
    with open(PATTERN_FILE) as inf:
        template = inf.read()

    with open(PARAMETERS_FILE) as inf:
        p1_lst = strs(next(inf, ""), ",")
        p2_lst = strs(next(inf, ""), ",")

    for p1, p2 in zip(p1_lst, p2_lst):
        fname = OUTPUT_NAME.format(p1=p1, p2=p2)
        data = template.replace("<p1>", p1).replace("<p2>", p2)
        with open(fname, "w") as outf:
            outf.write(data)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**Edit:** ok, if you want all combinations,

```
from itertools import product
```

and replace `for p1, p2 in zip(p1_lst, p2_lst):` with `for p1, p2 in product(p1_lst, p2_lst):`.

Comment: Hi @Hugh Bothwell thank you for the script. It is working fine. But probably my description was not complete. I would like build all possible combinations between the p1 and p2. Could you adjust the script. Thank you a lot in advance

Comment: Hi @Hugh Bothwell ... could add some explanations

Comment: @Drago: what would you like explained? If it is a particular function, Python has a really useful feature called `help()`, ie `help(product)`.